# Unity | Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I need some random int's for copied objects in canvas. So i created arrays that will fill with random values, but don't work and code stops on first array line (CPU_Model) and when i see array in unity editor it's empty (0 elements).
Sorry for wrong exploration or something like this, i'm new in coding.

```
 public int[] CPU_Model = new int[15];
    public int[] CPU_MHz = new int [15];
    public string[] CPU_Vars = new string[15];
    public int i = 0;

    public void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i<15; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
            CPU_Model[i] = Random.Range(400, 9999);
            CPU_MHz[i] = Random.Range(1200, 5400);
            CPU_Vars[i] = "CPU" + i;
            //i++;
        }
        //i = 0;
    }
```

Comment: In C# arrays start from index 0, not from 1

Comment: Your array size is 15, but you are only filling 14 locations (for [int i = 1; i<15; i++)].

Comment: You should setup these arrays in the inspector, the initialization `= new int[15]` cannot guarentee the array has a size of 15 in unity.

Answer (score 1):

In C# arrays start from index 0, not from 1.
So you should replace your code with

```
for (int i = 0; i<15; i++) {
  ....
}
```

Comment: great and also it shold be `i < 15`

Answer (score 1):

Array indices start at 0, so if you start your loop at 1, you will skip the first element of each array, and it will be uninitialized. To fix this, simply change your loop initialization to start at 0 instead of 1, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
```

Also, it's not necessary to declare the `i` variable as a class member if you're using it as a loop counter inside the `Start()` method. This local variable `i` shadows the class member variable `i`, which means that the `i` inside the loop is a separate variable from the `i` outside the loop. Since you only use the local variable `i` inside the loop and don't need to access its value **outside the loop**, there is no need to declare it as a class member.

```
public int[] CPU_Model = new int[15];
public int[] CPU_MHz = new int[15];
public string[] CPU_Vars = new string[15];

public void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        CPU_Model[i] = Random.Range(400, 9999);
        CPU_MHz[i] = Random.Range(1200, 5400);
        CPU_Vars[i] = "CPU" + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done, a good answer! You deserve my +1

Comment: About 0 and 1. Sorry for sending wrong number, but i also tried start from 0 and error occurs. And i need int i not for this loop, for next after this one. So not resolved yet.

Comment: @Ahmad_Coffee ok. So can you please an an info about where exactly (in what line of code) do you have an error? And is there a way to ensure that your Start method is completed when you watch 0 elements in ubity editor?

Comment: ```CPU_Model[i] = Random.Range(400, 9999);```
in this codeline error occurs and code cant continue so Start method cant be completed

Answer (score 0):

Already found solution. Array can't be public, so without it all system works correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).